# Joomla 3.4.8 Logged In Users seeing Error You are not authorised to view this resource on every page after login?

Tags: php, joomla

I have a login / register menu item which has the access level set to guest, so when the user logs in it becomes hidden.

When a user uses this menu item to login successfully it redirects them to the home page (which I assume is the default action) then the next page the user visits they get an error "You are not authorized to view this resource." appear above the page title but the page still loads fine regardless of which page it is. This only occurs on the first page they visit, if they refresh the page the error disappears.

However if I change the menu items access level to public once the user successfully logs in the menu item is still visible and the users account information is shown (there is no redirect to the home page) Now when the user clicks on any other page there is no errors and the page displays fine?

I'm using Joomla Version 3.4.8.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is probably due to ACL configuration of the menu items involved and redirect after login.
Scenario to reproduce issue:

- We create a login menu item visible only to guest users.
- Guest User clicks on login menu item and perform the login.
- After login, user is (by default, if no other redirection url is configured) redirected to profile user page, most probably this page doesn't have any menu item id associated, so by default joomla will get the Itemid from the last Itemid used by the user session, which in this case is the login menu item (not accessible by registered users, but only by guest users).
- So profile user page is not accessible and user is redirected to home page

Solution:
Make sure to redirect user after login to a valid accessible page (and related Itemid).

Example solution:
Configure the redirect url after login to: index.php?Itemid=HOMEPAGE_ITEM_ID

Replace HOMEPAGE_ITEM_ID with the correct value

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, this is an issue due to ACL (access level) for the menu item.

I had the same setup: a menu item "Login" with "guest" access level, and a "Logout" menu item with "registered" access level. The idea being only show login link for users who aren't signed in, and only show logout link for users that are.

The problem is that if you don't set a specific page to redirect to upon login, it reloads the page. If the "login" page is restricted to guest, and the user is signed in, they are warned "you are not authorized to view this resource."

**Solution:**

1. Create a new "hidden" menu in Joomla - not a new menu item, a
   separate menu.
2. Move your existing log in menu item to the new hidden
   menu.
3. Change the access setting from guest back to public.
4. Create a new menu item:

   a. For Menu Item Type, choose system, then alias.

   b. For Menu Item, choose the item we just moved to the hidden menu.

   c. For this menu item's access, choose guest.

The alias item will point to the hidden item. The hidden item will always be authorized, as it is public. The alias will only show for guests.

Comment: This all works as described except it seems to now ignore any menu you set as the redirect page, and always goes to the profile. Any ideas for that please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by adding the full URL in the redirect field instead of just home. Such as `http://www.your-domain.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Or grant the usergroup (from the user who can accept new users) access to "public" via the menu: users -> display acces level